# Is this a potential community wiki question?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Should [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110575/is-possible-to-upgrade-ios-offline) be made into a community wiki post, so we can just mark any "How do I go from iOS {x} to iOS {y}?" questions as a duplicate of this? Of course, we would need to rephrase the actual question be quite generic, but my answer on it has already been made as generic as possible. Perhaps it should just be a new question that I just ask and answer myself and mark as a wiki. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see why this sould be CW.

The question could be made a bit more general re the iOS versions but the answer seems to stay the same. Both seem good enough and covering an explict question so that they can be a normal answer

Comment: The problem is this: they all have the same exact answer, and the questions can all be formatted the exact same way, too.

Comment: So theyare duplicates - not CW

Comment: But which one are they a duplicate of? Maybe a Community Wiki isn't what I think it is...

Comment: If they all have teh same answer then they are all but one  duplicates

Comment: Would it then be acceptable for me to ask a new question in a very general way and then answer it myself in a very general way? (without making it a Community Wiki)

Comment: The question can't be too broad - but I would try and see. And Community Wiki is not relevantt here - mainly used for open ended questions asking for lists